# fail2ban non-standard log file rotation

Tags: fail2ban

I am running an application that is managing the apache access logs on the server.  The application is rotating the logs based on a size setting and is naming the logs by appending the date.

`example:
access_log.2020-01-10-11_06_38
access_log.2020-01-10-11_44_41
access_log.2020-01-10-12_45_37`

I believe the application is closing the file when it reaches the designated file size then opening a new file.

In my fail2ban config, I have my path setting as follows:

`logpath  = logs/apache/access_log.????-??-??-??_??_??`

When I start/restart fail2ban everything works great and reads until a new file is created and the logging moves to the newly created file.  It appears fail2ban does not see the file and has nothing to read until a restart/reload.

I know that fail2ban monitors the files with the "backend" setting, is there a way to set this so that it monitors the directory for new files or some other technique I can incorporate fail2ban for my situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FYI,

I solved my issue by creating a bash script that uses "inotifywait" to watch the log directory for changes, then updates a symlink to the most recent file.  The logpath in fail2ban is directed to the symlink.

Example:
fail2ban logpath:  /var/logs/apache/fail2banwatch

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="/var/logs/apache/"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE


do
if [[ ${NEWFILE} =~ \/var\/logs\/apache\/access_log\.????\-??\-??\-??_??_?? ]]
then

    ln -sfn ${NEWFILE} /var/logs/apache/fail2banwatch
        #echo ${NEWFILE}
fi
done
```